# tkinterを使用し、為替変換をしたい

Tags: python, tkinter

画像のような為替変換を行いたいのですが、うまく機能しません。画像の挿入方法もわかりません。
ご指摘、改善点お願いします。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
root=tkinter.Tk()

def convert():


    if radio_var.get() == 1: #chinese Yuan
        AusDollar = round(entry_var.get() * 0.209234,0)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Your ',str(entry_var), 'Chinese Yuan = ',str(AusDollar), ' in Australian Dollars')

    elif currency.upper() == 2: #Euro
        AusDollar = round(entry_var.get() * 1.59524,0)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Your ',str(entry_var), 'Euros = ',str(AusDollar), ' in Australian Dollars')

    elif currency.upper() == 3: #British Pound
        AusDollar = round(entry_var.get * 1.83338,0)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Your ',str(entry_var), 'British Pounds = ',str(AusDollar), ' in Australian Dollars')

    elif currency.upper() == 4: #Russian Ruble
        AusDollar = round(entry_var.get * 0.0214580,0)
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Your ',str(entry_var), 'Russian Rubles = ',str(AusDollar), ' in Australian Dollars')



main_frame = tkinter.Frame(root).grid()
radio_var = tkinter.IntVar()
radio_var.set(1)
entry_var = tkinter.IntVar()


#create butons

tkinter.Label(main_frame, text = "please select the currency to convert").grid(column=1, row=1)

tkinter.Radiobutton(main_frame, text="Chinese Yuan", variable=radio_var,
                    value=1).grid(column=1, row=2)
tkinter.Radiobutton(main_frame, text="Euro", variable=radio_var,
                    value=2).grid(column=1, row=3)
tkinter.Radiobutton(main_frame, text="British pound", variable =radio_var,
                    value=3).grid(column=1, row=4)
tkinter.Radiobutton(main_frame, text="Russian Ruble", variable=radio_var,
                    value=4).grid(column=1, row=5)
tkinter.Label(main_frame, text="How much money do you want to convert?:").grid(column=1, row=7)

tkinter.Entry(main_frame, textvariable= entry_var, width=10).grid(column=2, row=7)

tkinter.Button(main_frame,
                                text="Convert", command=convert).grid(column=1, row=8)
quit_button=tkinter.Button(main_frame, text ="Quit", command=root.destroy).grid(column=2, row=8)


tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: 質問欄の画像を見ますと裏写りしていますので、これは何らかの書籍のコピーなのでしょうか？ もしそうでしたら、出典の記載をお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

質問欄にあるコードでは `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo()` のパラメータ指定に誤りがあるのでエラーになってしまいます。

画像を挿入する処理は入れていないのですが、以下の様に書き換えてみました。

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Button, Radiobutton, Entry, messagebox
from tkinter import IntVar, W

conversion_table = {
  1: {'currency': 'Chinese Yuan',   'rate': 0.209234},
  2: {'currency': 'Euro',           'rate': 1.595240},
  3: {'currency': 'British Pounds', 'rate': 1.833380},
  4: {'currency': 'Russian Ruble',  'rate': 0.021458},
}

class CurrencyConverter(Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    Tk.__init__(self)
    self.currency = IntVar(value=1)
    self.money = IntVar(value=0)
    self.counter = 1

    # Widgets
    frame = Frame(self).grid()
    Label(
      frame, text='Please select the currency to convert'
    ).grid(column=1, row=self.row(), columnspan=4, sticky=W, padx=5)

    # Currencies
    for k, item in conversion_table.items():
      Radiobutton(
        frame, text=item['currency'], variable=self.currency, value=k
      ).grid(column=1, row=self.row(1), columnspan=4, sticky=W, padx=20)

    # Entry box
    Label(
      frame, text='How much money do you want to convert?'
    ).grid(column=1, row=self.row(1), columnspan=3, sticky=W, padx=5)
    entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=self.money, width=10)
    entry.grid(column=4, row=self.row(), padx=(1,10))
    entry.configure(
      validate='key', vcmd=(entry.register(
        lambda p: True if p.isdigit() or p == '' else False), '%P')
    )

    # Buttons for operations
    Button(
      frame, text='Convert', command=self.convert
    ).grid(column=1, row=self.row(1), columnspan=2, pady=(10,0))
    Button(
      frame, text='Quit', command=self.destroy
    ).grid(column=3, row=self.row(), columnspan=2, padx=(10,0), pady=(10,0))

  def convert(self):
    try:
      val = self.money.get()
    except:
      return
    currency =  conversion_table[self.currency.get()]
    aus_dollar = round(val * currency['rate'], 1)
    messagebox.showinfo(
      'Results',
      f'Your {val} {currency["currency"]} = {aus_dollar} in Australian Dollars'
    )

  def row(self, step=0):
    self.counter += step
    return self.counter

if __name__ == '__main__':
  gui = CurrencyConverter()
  gui.mainloop()
```