# PythonのGUIで参照方法がわからない

Tags: python, tkinter

PythonにてGUIを作成中で上手くいかない点があるため、質問させていただきます。

以下のようなコードを作成し、`input_label1` で参照した複数ファイルを合算し、`input_label2` と `input_label3` で入力した値を使用し、解析したいと考えています。

しかし、`name 'file_select' is not defined` というエラーが発生します。
`def init_star(self):` と同じインデントにする必要があるというのはわかるのですが、そうすると、GUIにボタンや入力ボックスが表示されなくなります。

どなたかご教授いただけないでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
import pydicom

import os
import pydicom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylinac import Starshot

class Gui():

  def init_star(self): 
 
#画像の合算      
    def file_select():
                  idir = r"C:\Users\tanim\OneDrive\デスクトップ"
                  file_path = tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = idir)
                  self.input_box1.insert(tkinter.END, file_path) #結果を表示
                
                
                
                  dicom_dir = file_path
                  image_sum = sum([
                      pydicom.dcmread(os.path.join(dicom_dir, f)).pixel_array
                      for f in os.listdir(dicom_dir)
                      if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dicom_dir, f)) and f.endswith('.dcm')
                    ])
                    
                  img = plt.imshow(image_sum)
                  img.set_cmap('gray')
                  plt.axis('off')
                  plt.margins(0,0)
                  plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
                  plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
                  plt.savefig("Starshot.tiff", bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)



#解析                   
    def pf_analyze():          
                
                  
                  mystar =Starshot(file_select,sid=self.input_box2.get(),dpi=self.input_box3.get())
                  mystar.analyze(radius=0.5, tolerance=0.8) 
                  print(mystar.results())
                  mystar.plot_analyzed_image()
                  mystar.publish_pdf('mystar2.pdf')
                  
 #入力欄の作成
    self.input_box1 = tkinter.Entry(width=40)
    self.input_box1.place(x=10, y=100)
            
    self.input_box2 = tkinter.Entry(width=40)
    self.ArithmeticErrorinput_box2.place(x=10, y=190)
           
    self.input_box3 = tkinter.Entry(width=40)
    self.input_box3.place(x=10, y=240)    
    
#ラベルの作成
    self.input_label1 = tkinter.Label()
    self.input_label1.place(x=10, y=70)
    self.input_label2 = tkinter.Label(text="sid")
    self.input_label2.place(x=10, y=160)
    self.input_label3 = tkinter.Label(text="dpi")
    self.input_label3.place(x=10, y=210)

#ボタンの作成
button1 = tkinter.Button(text="参照",command=file_select)
button1.place(x=10, y=40)
button2 = tkinter.Button(text="解析",command=pf_analyze)
button2.place(x=10, y=270)
          
#ウインドウの作成
root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Python GUI")
root.geometry("500x500")
                        
#ウインドウの描画
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: こんな記事とかが参考になるのでは？ [Pythonプログラム用にTkinterで画面（GUI）を作成する方法](https://gammasoft.jp/support/create-gui-by-tkinter/)

Comment: 質問とは別のこんな方法で簡単になるかも。[Tkinterを使うのであればPySimpleGUIを使ってみたらという話](https://qiita.com/dario_okazaki/items/656de21cab5c81cabe59), [PySimpleGUI ファイル選択](https://note.com/hideharu092/n/na4283eee8d44), [PythonとPySimpleGUIで画像変換ソフトを作ってみた話](https://tomomai.com/python_pysimplegui_viewer/)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。(https://gammasoft.jp/support/create-gui-by-tkinter/)　の参照方法を使用していたのですが、input_labelの値を参照しようとclassを設定したところインデントの影響か白紙のウィンドウが表示されるだけになってしまいました。PySimpleGUIは初耳でしたので勉強してみます！

Comment: 動いていた時のプログラムソースと画面の状態を追記し、それに何をどう追加しようとしたのかも追記してみてください。

Comment: そうですね、うまくお伝えできていなかったですね。大変失礼いたしました。いつもありがとうございます。また、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tkinterを使用し、為替変換をしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/63459/) を参考にしてコードを作成してみました。入力データのサニタイズやエラーチェックをしていないので、それらを追加する必要がありますが、たたき台としては丁度よいのではないかと思います。

```py
import os
import pydicom
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylinac import Starshot
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Label, Button, Entry, filedialog
from tkinter import StringVar, IntVar, W

STARSHOT_IMAGE_FILE = 'Starshot.tiff'

class AnalyzeImage(Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    Tk.__init__(self)
    self.file_path = StringVar(value='')
    self.sid = IntVar(value='')
    self.dpi = IntVar(value='')

    #DICOM画像フォルダを選択
    frame = Frame(self).grid()
    Button(
      frame, text='参照', command=self.file_select
    ).grid(sticky=W, padx=5, pady=10)
    self.file_path_box = Entry(frame, width=40, textvariable=self.file_path)
    self.file_path_box.grid(padx=5)

    #spacing
    Label(frame).grid()

    #sid, dpi
    Label(frame, text='sid').grid(sticky=W, padx=5)
    self.sid_box = Entry(frame, width=40, textvariable=self.sid)
    self.sid_box.grid(padx=5)
    Label(frame, text='dpi').grid(sticky=W, padx=5)
    self.dpi_box = Entry(frame, width=40, textvariable=self.dpi)
    self.dpi_box.grid(padx=5)
    Button(
      frame, text='解析', command=self.pf_analyze
    ).grid(sticky=W, padx=5, pady=10)

  #画像の合算      
  def file_select(self):
    idir = r"C:\Users\tanim\OneDrive\デスクトップ"
    #結果を表示
    self.file_path.set(filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir = idir))

    dicom_dir = self.file_path.get()
    image_sum = sum([
      pydicom.dcmread(os.path.join(dicom_dir, f)).pixel_array
      for f in os.listdir(dicom_dir)
      if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dicom_dir, f)) and f.endswith('.dcm')
    ])
                    
    img = plt.imshow(image_sum)
    img.set_cmap('gray')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.margins(0,0)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.NullLocator())
    plt.savefig(STARSHOT_IMAGE_FILE, bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)

  #解析
  def pf_analyze(self):
    mystar = Starshot(STARSHOT_IMAGE_FILE, sid=self.sid.get(), dpi=self.dpi.get())
    mystar.analyze(radius=0.5, tolerance=0.8) 
    print(mystar.results())
    mystar.plot_analyzed_image()
    mystar.publish_pdf('mystar2.pdf')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  gui = AnalyzeImage()
  gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。無事、ご提案いただいたコードで上手くいきました。何を改善すべきだったかこれから勉強します。